# How can an app claim to be able to transfer files hundreds of times faster than bluetooth?

Tags: performance, data-transfer

There is an android app that claims to have device-device transfer speeds which are much faster than the underlying protocols allow for:

> Amazing transferring speed
>
> 200 times Bluetooth speed! (Speed will be affected by the equipment & the surrounding). Thoroughly defeat BlueTooth/NFC/AirDrop. Better than all you know

I searched but can't find any discussion about this. How can this be possible?

Comment: Zapya is name of an app, where did you get the idea it relates to a technique?

Comment: This question is not [on topic](/help/on-topic) for Super User, but you *might* get some answers over at [android.stackexchange.com](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I have removed the link to the app's Store page in case of accusations of promotion- there is a quote of the relevant claim if folks want to find it. I think the claims amount to snake oil, but I'll let someone with greater knowledge weigh in.

Comment: Clever marketing? BT 2.0 is 3.0 Mbs max and Wireless 802.lln is 600 Mbs max. 3*200=600.

Comment: @DavidPostill hah, I guess. What's the spec for BT 1.0? I have another multiplier for their marketing team...

Comment: Not sure. BT 1.2 max is 0.7 Mbs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zapya uses **WiFi-direct** for connecting two devices. If you run to **create group** in Zapya it turns your WiFi off(disconnecting from internet) and turns your WiFi-Direct instead on and this coase your phone device to act as a WiFi hot spot for others.
On second device when you **search and join to group**, it turns WiFi on and search WiFi hot spot witch matches particular naming in Zapya formula. So two devices enter in private LAN with high speed connection.

[image]

Some other apps, for example SHAREit ,do this like Zapya. and on most new devices you can share a file throw WiFi Direct without any application.

But if your question is about how to increase data transfer through WiFi-Direct , I think it is a secret technical algorithm and they wont publish it somewhere in web.